# How to modify copy of value of object without altering original value in golang?

Tags: go, types, interface

Was facing some problem in altering value of object. I am new to goalng as well. Please consider the kind of example below.

```
//interface
type A interface{
GetVal() interface{}
}

//type which implements interface A
type B struct{
Val interface{}
}

func (j *B)GetVal() interface{}{
return j.Val
}

//function where object of B is getting created
func exmaple1(){
obj := &B{Val:"25"}
Example2(obj)
}


func Example2(handler A){
val := handler.GetVal()
example3(val1)
}

func example3(val1 interface{}){
// do some modifiaction on val1
}
```

My question here is, if i want to only modify the val1 (inside example3)to different value for say 10,and it should not alter the original value  handler.GetVal(),example 25 here.How do i do that??. How can i create a copy of handler.GetVal() and pass to function example3 so that altering only the copy of it not original.

### One more Question related to above

Instead of passing object value as string i am passing value as map[sting]interface{} as shown in below example,and modifying it in exmaple3 to add new key.

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
)

type A interface{
GetVal() interface{}
}

//type which implements interface A
type B struct{
Val interface{}
}

func (j *B)GetVal() interface{}{
return j.Val
}



func Example2(handler A){
val := handler.GetVal()
example3(val)
}

func example3(val1 interface{}){
// do some modifiaction on val1
val1.(map[string]interface{})["password"] = "heloo"

}
func main(){

obj := &B{Val:map[string]interface{}{"userName": "noob"}}
Example2(obj)

fmt.Println(obj)
}
```

Here if I modify the val1 in Example3 (for eg: adding a new key,) the obj also gets changed by getting added new key. How to avoid that ? what is the reason for it.? I dont want to alter the original obj.Only its copy should get changed. How can i create copy of obj and pass it to example3 so that only its copy gets modified and not original obj.How to acheive this?

https://play.golang.org/p/4EXHab6kIeZ

Comment: Show the code that modifies `val1` in `example3`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Muffin pointed out, `example3` will not modify `val1`. If you do want to modify the value you need to use `pointer receivers`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

//interface
type A interface {
    GetVal() interface{}
    SetVal(val interface{})
}

//type which implements interface A
type B struct {
    Val interface{}
}

func (j *B) GetVal() interface{} {
    return j.Val
}

func (j *B) SetVal(v interface{}) {
    j.Val = v
}

func Example(handler A) {
    val := handler.GetVal()
    inner(val)
}
func inner(val1 interface{}) {
    // do some modifiaction on val1
    val1 = 100
}

func SetExample(handler A, v interface{}) {
    handler.SetVal(v)
}

func main() {
    obj := &B{Val: "25"}
    Example(obj)
    fmt.Println(obj)

    SetExample(obj, 100)
    fmt.Println(obj)

}
```

https://goplay.space/#H9MD7pZMmVw

Comment: thanks@tomkaith13@muffin.Added one last example related to this question.